# Can OWA (Open Web Analytics) be used with Angular (2+) applications?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, web-analytics, openwebanalytics

Can someone please help me know if [OWA](https://github.com/Open-Web-Analytics/Open-Web-Analytics) can be used with Angular (2+) web applications.
I searched for it everywhere I can but could not find. It would also be of great help if you can help me know how to integrate it with angular.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the article [Tracking a web page using OWA's Javascript Tracker](http://demo.openwebanalytics.com/jstracker.php) with JS example. You can do the same in Angular. I didn't find the typing, so for TypeScript you will need to implement types yourself and just avoid types (which would probably lead to bugs).